# alert page if screen resolution is less than value

Tags: css, media-queries

regarding the css media queries, is there any possibility to call a page (html template) when the screen resolution is less than a predefined value please ?

I'm not a site developper and actually I'm not so sure how to build the css style...

Thank you,

LE:  it's about redirecting to a specified page, could be html in the end , something like this .Is this possible somehow ? Not so sure how to compose the url part.

```css
.getbacktodesk {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 99999;
  background: #f9f9f9;
}

.getbacktodesk:before {
  background:  url(http://neuegrid.com/?page_id=404404);

}


@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .getbacktodesk {
    display: block;
  }
  
 header, row, logoimg, #scroll_totop,
  nav,
  ._page {
    display: none; 
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="getbacktodesk"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this way is okay, you cannot action a php script via css!

```
<style>
@media (min-width: 600px) {

  body*{display:none;} 
//will display no element

  .alertmessage{display:block;}
//Put message in this div and display none in normal css queries.
}
</style>
```

Comment: I already tested a solution that can show a text message (as your above code) but it will be ok If I compose and save a page with different elements that could be called by the css .